# Wait for the state to load in vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have the following structure in my nuxt app.

**layout/admin.vue**

```js
  async mounted () {
    await this.loadState()
  },
  methods: {
    async loadState () {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
      const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId')
      const payload = {
        status: true,
        token,
        userId
      }
      if (token && userId) {
        await this.$store.commit('admin/loadUserData', payload)
      }
    console.log('Load State')
    }
}
```

The above code snippets stores the token and usertoken in the state.

**post/edit/_id.vue**

```js
export default {
  name: 'Edit',
  layout: 'admin',
  async mounted () {
        console.log('Load post data')
    try {
      const data = await this.$store.dispatch('post/editPost', this.$route.params.id)
      console.log(data)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.response)
    }
  }
  }
```

My state store **store/post.js**

```js
export const actions = {
   async editPost ({ rootState }, id) {
    const graphqlQuery = {
      query: `
        query{
          editPost(id: "${id}"){_id title content imageUrl}
        }
      `
    }
    console.log(rootState.admin.token)
    const res = await this.$axios.post('http://localhost:8080/graphql', graphqlQuery, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + rootState.admin.token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
    // console.log(res.data.data.editPost)
    return res.data.data.editPost
  }
}
```

When I go to the route `http://localhost:3000/admin/post/edit/{somepostId}` step wise (From post list to edit post) I get the post data.

But if I refresh the page I get the error.

The reason is when I refresh the page. The `console.log(rootState.admin.token)` is set to null.

I'm loading the data in state in `admin.vue` layout. How do I wait for the for the methods in `admin` layout to complete. Although I've used async await it is not waiting for the state to load data and they have been taking the initial blank data.

I've added console.log() in both methods **layout/admin** and **post/edit/_id**.

The console.log() from **post/edit/_id**. runs first when I hit refresh.

Comment: why you get data state in `admin.vue` , not `nuxtServerInit`  ?

Comment: How do I use nuxtServerInit in my scenario ?